# Python Graphic Draw

Tags: python, graphics, matplotlib, gaussian

tdondur x coordinate, y coordinate s.but i can't it. if you can help. Thank you all in advance. now only drawn tdondur value. how to plot the value of s.

```
from math import e, exp,pow 
import pylab
from gaussxw import gaussxwab

Kb=1.3806505*10**-23
V=10**-3
p=6.022*10**28
Qd=428.0


def f(x):
    isisigasi=9*V*p*Kb*(T/Qd)**3
    return(isisigasi*x**4*(exp(x))/(exp(2)-1)**2)

tut=[] 

Tdondur=range(5,501)
tut=[None for T in Tdondur] 

for tsirala, T in enumerate (Tdondur):
    N=50
    a=0
    b=Qd/T
    x,w=gaussxwab(N,a,b)
    s=0.0
    for k in range (N):
        s+=w[k]*f(x[k])    
    print(T,"'in Isı Sığası : ",s)
    print("----------------------------------------------------------")


pylab.plot(Tdondur)
pylab.title('Isı Sığasının Sıcaklığa Göre Değişimi')
pylab.xlabel('Sıcaklık (T)')
pylab.ylabel('Isı Sığası')
pylab.gcf().savefig('isisigasi.png')
pylab.show()
```

Comment: Can you check spelling and punctuation on the first couple of sentences? I wasn't able to figure out what you meant.

Comment: sorry, i am not speaking english. i am used google translate. x coordinate:tdondur, y koordinate: s. but i can't it.

Comment: i'm try it, but not working.
raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're calculating a new value for `s` in each iteration of the loop, but you never save what you calculate.  Instead, make an array for `s` before you enter the loop, and set `s[k]` within the loop.

```
from math import e, exp,pow 
import pylab
from gaussxw import gaussxwab

Kb=1.3806505*10**-23
V=10**-3
p=6.022*10**28
Qd=428.0


def f(x):
    isisigasi=9*V*p*Kb*(T/Qd)**3
    return(isisigasi*x**4*(exp(x))/(exp(2)-1)**2)

tut=[] 

Tdondur=range(5,501)
tut=[None for T in Tdondur] 

s = [0. for i in Tdondur]  # initialize s before entering the loop
for tsirala, T in enumerate (Tdondur):
    N=50
    a=0
    b=Qd/T
    x,w=gaussxwab(N,a,b)
    for k in range (N):
        s[k]+=w[k]*f(x[k])    # work on the values within the loop

pylab.plot(Tdondur, s)
#s_np = pylab.array(s)
#pylab.plot(Tdondur, pylab.log10(s_np))
pylab.title('title')
pylab.xlabel('T')
pylab.ylabel('Y')
#pylab.gcf().savefig('')
pylab.show()
```

Here's the result (note that the x-axis is magnified):

[image]

Typically for data like this you would want to plot the `log` of the data, and to do that, uncomment the two lines after that read:

```
s_np = pylab.array(s)
pylab.plot(pylab.log10(s_np))
```

(Note that the above lines are using numpy, which is imported with pylab, and is easier than list comprehensions for this type of problem.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I did what you said. However, I received the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

    raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Comment: The code I show runs in my system, so I think it will work for you.  Restart your system and run my code exactly as shown (that is, don't edit your code but copy and paste my code directly).  Your error could still be caused by `s` not being a list or array, so that's probably still your problem.  For example, do you still have the line `s=0.0`?  You should NOT have this line.

Comment: no copy paste. s = 0.0 in the sheen on the error:AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'rint' . If s = 0.0 when :ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you try a different translator?

Comment: s=0.0 in this code :AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'rint' . s=0.0 absence in this code: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Comment: OK, I understand.  Did you copy and paste my code, or edit your code?  That is, are you running my exact code?  Also, to debug, use `Tdondur=range(5,20)` and then `print Tdondur` and `print s`.  Also, which line has the error?

Comment: no copy paste. edited this code. i am tried Tdontur 5 to 20. bu not working. Error massage : AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'rint'

Comment: OK. I think the language translation is too difficult, and I don't think that I'll be able to help you fix this. But I suggest: USE MY CODE, DO NOT EDIT YOURS.